# Not able to start VM - Resource 'disk' is not ready

Tags: google-compute-engine

Recently we have issue with our billing and after resolving the issue we are not able to start the VMs again. we are getting error with code 400 and the message say 
`The resource 'projects/xxxxxxxxx/zones/xxxxxx/disks/xxxxxx' is not ready`
we looked at the disk and found the disk status is `RESTORING` this `RESTORING` is going on for days. 
I have tried create a new vm instance and found error with same error code (400) this time its say default `The resource 'projects/xxx/global/networks/default' is not ready` 
Any help will be highly appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better for your to open a [support ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs) with Google so they can look at it in more detail.

Comment: You may also try [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) and report an issue there to get free support - it may take a while but may be worth the wait.